# Event/notification of member modification in C++

Tags: c++, events, notify

```
class A{
  int i;
};

class B{
  // sense i is changed by A    
};
```

If the value of `i` is changed by A, then B should get notified. Any suggestion how to implement this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you looking for the [Observer Design Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern)?

Answer (score 1):

The [Observer pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern) is the standard way to implement this. There are lots of pointers in the Wikipedia article, and on the Web (just google "observer pattern c++").

Answer (score 1):

Look at the [observer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern) or publisher-subscriber pattern.

Answer (score 1):

The `Observer Pattern` is the main solution to your problem.

You could also use `SIGNALS` and `SLOTS`. There are two main libraries which implement them:

1) [Boost](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/doc/html/signals.html)

2) [QT](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/signalsandslots.html) (although it's a large library for using just the `SIGNAL` and `SLOT` api)

Answer (score 1):

You need a different implementation for your classes:

```
class B {

public:
  Alert(int value_changed) {
     // implement whatever you want
     // for example printf("Value has changed to %i class A!!!\n", value_changed);
       }

}


class A {
/* constructor implementation */
 A(int i) {
           internal_value = i;
           B_class = new B() //notice that B will automatically be created by A!
          }

~A() { delete B_class; }

public:

 ChangeValue(int new_value) {
           internal_value = new_value;
           B_class.Alert(internal_value);
           }

private:

int internal_value;
B *B_class;

}

int main() {

A my_A(10); // you implicitly create a pair of classes A - B;

my_A.ChangeValue(20); // you should notice that A calls B automatically

return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

C++ does not provide this feature out of the box, you have to program it on your own. I guess you should read into the design pattern [Observer pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern) to achieve this.